"today" keyword inside Query Template inside PnP Modern search result web part is not respecting the site regional settings
I have a SharePoint Online site collection with these regional settings (Pacific Time): -

And I am using this Search Query Template inside PnP search result web part to get the items which have their RefinableDate01 =today , as follow:-
{searchTerms} ContentType:"Carrier"

RefinableDate01=today

where the RefinableDate01 is linked to a SharePoint Date/Time field named "PU-ETA". now i am facing this problem:-
1- Currently the time is 03:40 am Pacific Time + 10:40 am UTC.
2- I added a list item and i defined the PU-ETA Date/Time as "8/21/2024 10:00 pm ":-

3- This will be stored inside SharePoint using UTC which will be "2024-08-22T05:00:00Z".
So when i do a search using this Query Template: -
{searchTerms} ContentType:"Carrier"

RefinableDate01=today

I will get the above item, although based on the site time zone which the user follow this item is not for today 22 August (based on their timezone) it is for yesterday 21 August.. so how i can fix this? so i can do the check for today based on the site settings timezone? and not based on UTC? so when the user specifies the Date/Time to be PU-ETA as 8/21/2024 10 pm this item should be shown inside the Today report on 21 August Pacific Time ??
Thanks
